# How to change font color after accepting zsh-autosuggestions' recommendation

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I used to use fish, which has this realy useful and good autosuggestion. 
Recently I tried to start using zsh and install the zsh-autosuggestions plugin.\

But I noticed that if I accept the recommendation of the plugin, the font color won't automaticcaly change back to the normal color, remaining the `fg` value set in the zsh-autosuggestions.sh file.

[image: accepting vs typing]

In fish, the font color would look the same in both accepting and typing condition.
[image: In fish, it looks the same]

I'm using `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` in `arch` with `oh-my-zsh`.

I tried to change the theme (`lambda` or `headline`) and the terminal (`alacritty` or `yakuake`), but nothing happened. 
Is it normal? Or there is something that I messed up. 
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: @Adriaan Thank u for your reminder. I used images here to show the difference between accepting the suggestions versus manully typing the command, so I think images here are indeed necessary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.